# How to run async Operation

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I have this custom operation:

```
class CustomOperation: Operation {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    }

    override func main() {
        // ..
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm doing to run the `CustomOperation`:

```
let customOperation = CustomOperation()
customOperation.completionBlock = { print("custom operation finished") }
customOperation.start()
```

I have a few `CustomOperation`s trying to run at the same time. Is anyway to run it async without creating an `OperationQueue` for each `CustomOperation`? Because the `isAsynchronous` property is read only.

Comment: I would recommend you stay away from `Operation` and `OperationQueue`, and use the `Dispatch` library instead. It's been updated for Swift so it's nicer and easier to use, it's more flexible, and it's actually what `Operation`/`OperationQueue` use internally. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Alexander I'm trying to perform a task for each object from an array displayed on a `UITableView`. If an object will be displayed on a `UITableViewCell`, the operation starts. For style reasons I have using `Operation` and `OperationQueue`.

Comment: "Style reasons"?

Comment: So you have (for example) 10 objects, processing them asynchronously, then collecting the results to show on the table view, all at once?

Comment: @Alexander for the Style reasons, I mean, I use it because in previous versions of Swift, `Dispatch` was a C API style, I guess I have to give it a try. I load all that objects (the only visible) at once to make the UI faster when the user select one row to open the next view controller.

Comment: Yeah, that's not at all the case anymore. Dispatch was given a makeover specifically for Swift. It uses closures, optionals, proper naming, the whole shebang. It also doesn't rely on the Objective C runtime, so its methods are faster, too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a queue for each operation. You can put them all in the same queue.  The queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` determine's how many are run simultaneously.

If you don't want to use a queue at all, you need to override start() and isAsynchronous() and have start() start a thread and run.  There is more you need to do than that (read the docs)

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation

Go to the "Methods to Override Section"

> If you are creating a concurrent operation, you need to override the following methods and properties at a minimum:
>
> - start()
> - isAsynchronous
> - isExecuting
> - isFinished
>
> In a concurrent operation, your start() method is responsible for starting the operation in an asynchronous manner. Whether you spawn a thread or call an asynchronous function, you do it from this method. Upon starting the operation, your start() method should also update the execution state of the operation as reported by the isExecuting property. You do this by sending out KVO notifications for the isExecuting key path, which lets interested clients know that the operation is now running. Your isExecuting property must also provide the status in a thread-safe manner.